# Can't fit ImageView on screen

Tags: android

How to fit image fully on screen? I need to have `WRAP_CONTENT`, not `MATCH_PARENT`

```
im.setImageResource(resource);
im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
im.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This codes places the image on upper part so bottom is grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove
`im.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`

It adjusts bounds to preserve the aspect ratio the drawable are you displaying.

Comment: can you able to explain what is the error or convert this to  a anser